# How load/save a number with saved games for Play Games Services in Unity games?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I need to load/save the number of coins a user has earned in my Unity game with saved games for Play Games Services.

There is an example on how to save an image on this page: https://developer.android.com/games/pgs/unity/saved-games#write_a_saved_game

Can someone tell me how I can load/save a number instead of an image?

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, I wouldn't say you are exactly saving an image. I mean, you do save it, but only as a cover for your game save file and I don't know if you can retrieve it (maybe you can, I haven't checked that really).

Probably the most important part of using google play save system is `byte[] savedData` argument. It's just a byte array, and it's up to you what are you going to pass there and how are you going to interpret that data on game load.

There are a lot of ways you could approach it. I personally create a custom GameSave object with all my data that I want to save, then I serialize it using `JsonUtility`.

```
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(gameSave);
```

After that, I use `MemoryStream` and `BinaryFormatter` to convert the data in my json to byte array:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, json);
byte[] data = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
```

Then you would have to pass that data to `savedGameClient.CommitUpdate` method as an argument.

Of course, that's just one of the ways of doing that, you can send something else than json from serialized class object.

Other stuff is pretty well documented, so once you handle that, you should manage to do the rest.